# how to set bool array in InlineAutoData tag in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I want to test a method. A Boolean array is required to test this method. How can I set this array in the InlineAutoData tag? My code example is as follows

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineAutoData([true,false,false])]
    public void ToEntityTest(bool[] groups, HeadModel model)
    {
        model.Groups = new HeadGroupsModel()
        {
            Groups = groups
        };
        var headModel = model.ToEntity().ToModel().ToEntity();
        headModel.Should().BeEquivalentTo(model.ToEntity());
    }
```

It is not working. groups are created automatically, not what I set.
Thank you for all attention and support.

Comment: Can you elaborate - what doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: Groups are created automatically, not what I set

Answer (score 0):

Use params argument

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(true,false,false)]
public void ToEntityTest(params bool[] groups)
{
    var model = new HeadModel
    {
        Groups = new HeadGroupsModel { Groups = groups }
    }

    var headModel = model.ToEntity().ToModel().ToEntity();
    headModel.Should().BeEquivalentTo(model.ToEntity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proper array:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoData(new bool[true,false,true])]
public void ToEntityTest(bool[] groups, HeadModel model)
{
    model.Groups = new HeadGroupsModel()
    {
        Groups = groups
    };
    var headModel = model.ToEntity().ToModel().ToEntity();
    headModel.Should().BeEquivalentTo(model.ToEntity());
}`
```